# I am working on a fabric mod and I have issues with the ClientOnInitialize method

Tags: java, json, intellij-idea, minecraft, fabric

simply put nothing inside th oninitialise method runs the public class TutorialModClient appears grey in IntelliJ .I have all the necessary entries in my fabric.mod.json :
the json entries are

```
"entrypoints": {
        "main": [
            "net.example.vladimir.TutorialMod"
        ],
        "client": [
            "net.example.vladimir.TutorialModClient"
        ],
        "fabric-datagen": [
            "net.example.vladimir.TutorialModDataGenerator"
        ]
    },
```

I tried to look on the fabric API but its says about the entry points which I have done and I could not find anything else that could help:

my code for MyModClient

```
package net.example.me;
import ...

public class TutorialModClient implements ClientModInitializer {
    @Override
    public void onInitializeClient() {
        EntityRendererRegistry.register(ModEntities.PORCUPINE, PorcupineRenderer::new);
        EntityModelLayerRegistry.registerModelLayer(ModModelLayers.PORCUPINE, PorcupineModel::getTexturedModelData);
    }
}
```

I was following a tutorial by the youtube Kaupenjoe just in case.

Comment: Can you share the youtube tutorial link you are using?